# Tableau Gantt bar coloring from specific date

Tags: gantt-chart, tableau-desktop

Using Tableau, I would like to create a Gantt Bar where the area of each bar to the left of TODAY() has one color and the area of each bar to the right of TODAY() has another color.

Any ideas?

Comment: welcome to S.O.F. ; try to add a sample input of your data in order to better undrstand how to help you, and if possible a screen of what you accomplished so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your Gantt chart is made, but probably the best way to do it would be to create a `Calculated Field` like this

```
IF [Day] >= TODAY() THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
END
```

and the drag and drop on the *Color* square in the *Marks* panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FYI, You can shorten the calc to just “[DAY] >= TODAY()”. Same effect. The IF etc is redundant.